# Start workers when a DynamicSupervisor starts

Tags: elixir

I've implement a DynamicSupervisor that handle workers that use `Process.send_after/3` to send push notification with some time precision.

In some cases, like when I release a new version without hotswap functionality, I want to keep a record of all workers still not completed in DETS, and when the DynamicSupervisor starts to create all this workers again with the same state that was saved in DETS.

I know that [DynamicSupervisor](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/DynamicSupervisor.html) don't support workers right from start, and I should implement `start_child` to start a new worker, but don't know how I can integrate the start of the DynamicSupervisor with the start of theses workers on the same module.

I've tried different approaches, but without success (`Task.async`, `Process.send_after`, etc).

Should I implement the starting behaviour in other part of the code (I'm using Phoenix) ?

EDIT: I've found a small issue (expecting %{x:1, y:2} and was receiving [x: 1, y:2]

This is the init function on the DynamicSupervisor.

```
...

def init(arg) do
  Task.async(fn ->
    start_lost_children()
  end)

  DynamicSupervisor.init(arg)
end

def start_child(data) do
  spec = {MyApp.Worker, %{data: data}}

  DynamicSupervisor.start_child(__MODULE__, spec)
end

...
```

This is the error message that I get, altough isn't affecting the behaviour of the DynamicSupervisor.

```
[error] DynamicSupervisor received unexpected message: {#Reference<0.2565843855.2975858690.212433>, :ok}

[error] DynamicSupervisor received unexpected message: {:DOWN, #Reference<0.2565843855.2975858690.212433>, :process, #PID<0.593.0>, :normal}
```

The `:ok` is the result of `start_lost_children/0` return.

If I implement `handle_info/2`, it doesn't catch anything.

Comment: Would you please restate what your question is exactly, like “How would I start _that_ from _this_ under _thes_ circumstances”? Did I understand properly that the question is “How do I load config from DETS and start processes defined by this config from `DynamicSupervisor`”?

Comment: @mudasobwa the question is, how to start workers from DynamicSupervisor as soon DynamicSupervisor is started. There where an issue with my code, that was the main cause (expecting a map, receiving an array), not works with 2 minor issues that I will update on the topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am putting this here mostly for the sake of code formatting; the code below works for me in the same situation under same conditions in my project. I am not sure it would help, since you have explicitly mentioned you have tried sorta this approach, but since there in no code in the OP I can compare against, here we go.

The process that starts tasks, should implement these two `handle_info/2` callbacks:

```rb
@doc false
# Task finished {#Reference<0.0.1.6335>, :ok}
def handle_info({_pid, _payload}, state),
  do: {:noreply, state}

@doc false
def handle_info({:DOWN, _ref, :process, _pid, :normal}, state),
  do: {:noreply, state}
```

Optionally you might want to explicitly handle the latter for other return states besides `:normal`.

---

`init` is not the appropriate place to put `Task.async/1` because `init/1` is a callback that is called from the process, that starts your custom `DynamicSupervisor`. This process will receive `info` messages back, (see, your error messages report *`DynamicSupervisor` does not implement handlers*.)

The below should work (assuming both respective `handle_info/2` are implemented):

```rb
def start_link(arg) do
  with link <- DynamicSupervisor.start_link(...) do
    Task.async(...)
    link
  end
end

@impl true
def init(args) do
  DynamicSupervisor.init(args)
end
```

Comment: Thanks for you comment. In first part notice that the DynamicSupervisor is the one that receives the handle_info and not my supervisor. So adding `handle_info/2` don't change anything. Using Task.async on `start_link` will throw the same exception as `init`.

Comment: Have you read my answer at all? There is an explanation why it’s `DynamicSupervisor` receiving `handle_info/2` accompanied with a receipt on _how to overcome that_.

Comment: Ok, it isn't `DynamicSupervisor`, but is `Supervisor` now. `[error] Supervisor received unexpected message:`.

Comment: I end up following this, https://elixirforum.com/t/starting-children-of-dynamic-supervisors-on-application-startup/2278. Have a worker that starts and read the DETS and create all the children.

Answer (score 2):

`Task.async/1` starts a task that must be awaited on. Developers must eventually call `Task.await/2` or `Task.yield/2`.

Try `Task.start/1` - this is only used when the task is used for side-effects (i.e. no interest in the returned result) and it should not be linked to the current process.